# Many to Many relationship - get double rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Well just like the title says, I have a many to many relationship in my project, when customer can have many coupons and the other way. To make that work I made another table in MySQL which include coupon id and customer id(each row)but somehow every time I add a coupon to a customer It double its rows in coupon_customer table. 
for example:

coupon-> id 1

customer->id 4

[first add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85F0b.jpg)

now I add another coupon(id 2) to the same customer and that's the result:

[second add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9un0X.jpg)

my code:

Customer:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH,
            CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinTable(name = "coupon_customer", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "coupon_id"))
    private List<Coupon> coupons;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String name, String password) {

        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.coupons = new ArrayList<Coupon>();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public List<Coupon> getCoupons() {

        return coupons;
    }

    public void setCoupons(ArrayList<Coupon> coupons) {
        this.coupons = coupons;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", password=" + password + "]";
    }

}
```

Coupon:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "coupon")
public class Coupon {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "start_date")
    private Date startDate;

    @Column(name = "end_date")
    private Date endDate;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private int amount;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "type")
    private CouponType type;

    @Column(name = "message")
    private String message;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private double price;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH,
            CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinTable(name = "coupon_customer", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "coupon_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id"))
    private List<Customer> customers;

    public Coupon() {
    }

    public Coupon(String title, Date startDate, Date endDate, int amount, CouponType type, String message,
            double price) {

        this.title = title;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.type = type;
        this.message = message;
        this.price = price;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public CouponType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(CouponType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        return customers;
    }

    public void setCustomers(List<Customer> customers) {
        this.customers = customers;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Coupon [id=" + id + ", title=" + title + ", startDate=" + startDate + ", endDate=" + endDate
                + ", amount=" + amount + ", type=" + type + ", message=" + message + ", price=" + price + "]";
    }
```

CustomerController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/purchaseCoupon")
    public ResponseEntity<CouponSystemResponse> purchaseCoupon(@RequestParam(value = "id") int id) {
        try {

            Coupon coupon = couponService.getCoupon(id);
            getEntity().getCoupons().add(coupon); --> getEntity() gets the customer 
            coupon.setAmount(coupon.getAmount() - 1);
            customerService.updateCustomer(getEntity()); --> updates customer after purchase coupon
            couponService.updateCoupon(coupon); --> update coupon after been purchased(amount -1)

.....
```

and if that helps MySQL script:

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `couponsystem`;

CREATE SCHEMA `couponsystem`;

use `couponsystem`;



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `company`;

CREATE TABLE `company` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `password` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `coupon`;

CREATE TABLE `coupon` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_id` int(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_company_id` (`company_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_company_id` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `company` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customer`;

CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `password` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `coupon_customer`(
`coupon_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
/*
PRIMARY KEY (`coupon_id`,`customer_id`), --> that's in comment only cause I got exception every time row doubles itself and tried looking for solutions
*/
CONSTRAINT `FK_coupon_id` FOREIGN KEY (`coupon_id`) REFERENCES `coupon` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_customer_id` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

);
```

CustomerService:

```
@Service
public class CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository customerRepo;


    .....

    public void updateCustomer(Customer customer) {
        customerRepo.save(customer);
    }

   .....
```

CouponService:

```
@Service
public class CouponService {

    @Autowired
    CouponRepository couponRepo;

    ......
    public void updateCoupon(Coupon coupon) {
        couponRepo.save(coupon);
    }
    ......
```

Weird stuff.Like it takes all the last rows add them and then add another rows. I thought i something with cascade but couldn't make that work.... appreciate any help.

Comment: where is the function running the INSERT queries? I don't see them... is it insert select, how do the insert function get the coupon and customer?

Comment: @GuyL I'm using CrudRepository with Hibernate...

Comment: I don't know what that means...

Comment: I now update the main post

Comment: Do you have a Coupon_Customer class? Or you're just using that as a join table between the two entities?

Comment: @Matheus Cirillo I used it as a join table between the entities

Comment: That's the main problem. I'll write an answer. Your primary key at coupon_customer are composed and you're not mapping them.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all I would add another constraint to the coupon_customer table, a unique combination, provided with an INSERT IGNORE conmand, that will skip insert errors, it will provide basic db protection of such errors

```
ALTER TABLE coupon_customer ADD  UNIQUE KEY coupon_customer (coupon_id, customer_id);
```

and the INSERT should be:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO...
```

Beyond that, the function generating the query should receive exactly one parameter for each key and generate the simplest query. If the insert js built with select or the function works on the function with arrays, then these can generate errors as you described

```
public function add coupon($customer_id, $coupon_id) {
... 

$sql =  "INSERT IGNORE INTO coupon_customer VALUES (". $customer_id . ",". $coupon_id . ");" ;
... 
}
```

Comment: I already have it bro.. check the post                                                           
        PRIMARY KEY (`coupon_id`,`customer_id`),

Comment: it's a partial solution since it protects the db (like the 1st part of my answer) but it won't fix the code that still generates a wrong query

Answer (score 0):

Your `Coupon_Customer` primary key should be composed by two fields (`customer_id` and `coupon_id`).

Looking at your code, you don't have any primary key at this table. That's the main problem.

In order to create a composed primary key in Spring Data JPA, you do need a `@Embeddable` annotated class, which will represent your `coupon_customer_id`.

Something like the following:

**CouponCustomerId.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class CouponCustomerId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "coupon_id")
    private Long couponId;

    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private Long customerId;

    public CouponCustomerId(Long couponId, Long customerId) {
        this.couponId = couponId;
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    // getters and setters..
}
```

Now, you'll need to create a CouponCustomer entity with an `@EmbeddedId`, which will represent your composed primary key.

**CouponCustomer.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.MapsId;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class CouponCustomer {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CouponCustomerId id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) // add your own ManyToOne configurations
    @MapsId("couponId")
    private Coupon coupon;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) // add your own ManyToOne configurations
    @MapsId("customerId")
    private Customer customer;

    // getters and setters..
}
```

Now, at your `Customer` entity, you'll have to change your `List<Coupon>` to `List<CouponCustomer>` and change the relationship to `@OneToMany`.

**Customer.java**

```
....
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
    CascadeType.PERSIST,
    CascadeType.MERGE,
    CascadeType.DETACH,
    CascadeType.REFRESH
})
private List<CouponCustomer> coupons;
....
```

Same thing for the `Coupon` entity.

**Coupon.java**

```
....
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "coupon" fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
    CascadeType.PERSIST,
    CascadeType.MERGE,
    CascadeType.DETACH,
    CascadeType.REFRESH
})
private List<CouponCustomer> customers;
....
```

Now, each time you add a coupon to a customer, you just need to relate it's ids.

Something like the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/purchaseCoupon")
public ResponseEntity < CouponSystemResponse > purchaseCoupon(@RequestParam(value = "id") int id) {
    try {

        Coupon coupon = couponService.getCoupon(id);
        coupon.setAmount(coupon.getAmount() - 1);
        couponService.updateCoupon(coupon); -->update coupon after been purchased(amount - 1)

        CouponCustomer cc = new CouponCustomer();
        // assuming that getEntity() gets your Customer
        cc.setCoupon(coupon);
        cc.setCustomer(getEntity();
        cc.setId(new CouponCustomerId(coupon.getId(), getEntity().getId()));
        couponCustomerService.save(cc);
        .....
```

Keep in mind that, in order to update the `Coupon` and creating a record in `Coupon_customer`, you **don't need** to call `customerService.updateCustomer`.

At

```
cc.setId(new CouponCustomerId(coupon.getId(), getEntity().getId()));
couponCustomerService.save(cc);
```

You're creating a record to the coupon_customer table, with the composed primary key (`coupon_id`, `customer_id`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.orel.couponsystem.entity.CouponCustomer from com.orel.couponsystem.entity.Coupon has the wrong number of column. should be 2

Comment: thanks for help. I now get this exception when trying to run the app:(: above me) @Matheus Cirillo

Comment: by the way couldn't it work with @JoinTable annotation? cause I did see it working other places..

Comment: @hindi1991 have you removed the `@JoinColumn` at `List<CouponCustomer>` in both Coupon and Customer entities?

Comment: well i did now and looks like it works... but that created me 3 more tables in MySQL schema: coupon_customer, coupon_customers, customer_coupons, should it be like it? one more thing when I use the controller as you said Im getting this error: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.orel.couponsystem.entity.CouponCustomer.coupon]; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.orel.couponsystem.entity.CouponCustomer.coupon]

Comment: @hindi1991 no, it's not right that hibernate created 3 extra tables. It should've create only one (coupon_customer). Could you update the question, showing how's your mapping now, after the changes I proposed? About your error, my bad.. forgot to tell that you have to set the Customer and the Coupon into the CouponCustomer entity. Answer updated at your controller code.